# Update calendar event with attachments in a google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to find the next upcoming event in my calendar by the summary/title an event called "production meeting".

I want to attach a file from my google drive to this event.

So far I've managed to search for the event and find the first one - as I want to.
From there it's a little more messy... I've managed to create a new event from the details in the previous found event. But I haven't managed to attach the file to the event... and it's not really what I want.

So if anyone can point me in the right direction. So that I can **update** the found event with an attachment.

```js
function calUpdate() {
//Find produktion meeting event within a date range
var startSearch = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+4));
var endSearch = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+9));

var prodMeeting = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("****@****.com");
var prodEvent = prodMeeting.getEvents(startSearch, endSearch,{search:"production meeting"});

Logger.log(startSearch+ " // "+endSearch+" // "+ prodEvent+" // "+prodEvent.length);

var eventId = prodEvent[0].getId();

var event = prodMeeting.getEventById(eventId);

//Logger.log(eventId);

var eventStart = event.getStartTime();
var eventEnd = event.getEndTime();

//Logger.log("EventTime: "+eventStart+" // "+eventEnd);

var calendarEvent = {
    summary: 'production meeting',
    description: 'Test',
    location: 'Office',
    start: {
      dateTime: eventStart.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: eventEnd.toISOString()
    },
    attachments: [{
      'fileId': '****docId****',
      'title': "Test"
    }],
//    attendees: [{
//      email: 'guest2@guest.com'
//    }, {
//      email: 'guest2@guest.com'
//    }]
  };

calendarEvent = Calendar.Events.insert(calendarEvent, "****@****.com");


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your calendar using either [Calendar.Events.update()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) or [Calendar.Events.Patch()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch). The difference between these two is that in update, all the data specified in your call will be set to your event (and the rest will be unset) whereas using `Patch()` only the data that you specify is modified (and the of the event's properties are left as they were).
You can see an example  below:

```js
function calUpdate() {
  var startSearch = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+4));
  var endSearch = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+9));
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('<YOUR_CALENDAR_ID>');
  var foundEvents = calendar.getEvents(startSearch, endSearch,{search:"production meeting"});
  var event = foundEvents[0];

  var patch = {
    attachments: [{
      'fileUrl': '<YOUR_FILE_URL>',
      'title': 'Test'
    }]
  }

  var eventId = event.getId().split("@google.com")[0];
  Calendar.Events.patch(patch, 'primary', eventId, {"supportsAttachments": true});
}
```

Bear in mind that at the moment, it is only supported to attach Drive files.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.